# Get all page-layouts for an object via API

Tags: api, metadata, page-layout

I am attempting to get all page-layouts (w/ details) for a given object via the API.

Currently using [describeLayout](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_describelayout.htm) which gives me the details I would need about a layout, the problem with this is that it only returns the layouts applicable for the calling user.  I would like to get all the possible layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`describeLayout` is for use with applications that render pages that directly interface with salesforce.com, such as canvas apps, mobile apps, and so on. To get all of the layouts, take a look at the [Metadata API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/), and in particular, the "File-based" calls.

Comment: so essentially retrieving and parsing the XML definition of the layouts.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the only solution. The SOAP API was designed with the intent of allowing third-party application developers to have all the information they needed to create salesforce.com-driven interfaces, while the Metadata API was created to allow programmatic administrative interfaces.