# API to get all sales stages

Tags: rest-api, api

Is there an API where I can get all sales stages from an organization?

Is a sales stage equivalent to a layout? I found this: [Get all page-layouts for an object via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/get-all-page-layouts-for-an-object-via-api) and maybe it's the same question, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

In the REST API, if you hit the Opportunity/describe endpoint, current url seems to be:

```
https://naXX.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Opportunity/describe
```

The sales stages are in the response, in fields->n->picklistValues, where n is the index of the field whose label is Stage.

Comment: Except that editing the sales stages using the Customize feature and then re-running this API request did not get me my custom sales stage. Back to looking for more info.

Comment: Turns out SF has slow caching and the edits were available the next day.

Comment: Hey, @freyley, it looks like your URL is using API 20.0. YOu may want to just update that to API 30.0, which is the current version with Spring '14.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using the Schema and describe results in order to find all of the Stages.  That field is a 'picklist' field.  Layouts and Stages are completely different things.

Comment: Can you point me at any of the Schema documentation? I'm not seeing Schema referenced here, for example: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm

Comment: I can't atm... for some reason everything is coming up as 404 pages.  The closest thing I found probably has some similar version among the rest API:  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm

Comment: That's really helpful for doing this in Apex. Thanks!