# How to retrieve all available page layouts for an object?

Tags: metadata-api, jsforce

I'm using the jsforce node package and I've tried the following:

```
conn.metadata.retrieve(
    {
        apiVersion: '38.0',
        unpackaged: {
            types: [
                {
                    members: ['Contact'],
                    name: 'Layout'
                }
            ]
        }
    }
).stream().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('contact.zip'));
```

Which results in the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Contact</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <version>38.0</version>
</Package>
```

I'm not sure where to retrieve all layouts from. I can do it via the `describeLayouts()` endpoint, but that seems to exclude the actual layout names which I definitely need.

I referenced [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14391/get-all-page-layouts-for-an-object-via-api) and turned to the metadata file-based API calls which is shown above. I also did `name: 'CustomObject'` but it wasn't part of that response either. Any ideas?

Edit with REST API response:
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Tooling API to query for the layouts:

```
SELECT FullName FROM Layout WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'Contact'
```

You can read more about the [Tooling API REST Calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_rest_overview.htm).

Here's the raw endpoint you would use:

```
/services/data/v38.0/tooling/query?q=SELECT+FullName+FROM+Layout+WHERE+TableEnumOrId=%27Contact%27
```

Example Output:

```
{
  "size" : 1,
  "totalSize" : 1,
  "done" : true,
  "queryLocator" : null,
  "entityTypeName" : "Layout",
  "records" : [ {
    "attributes" : {
      "type" : "Layout",
      "url" : "/services/data/v38.0/tooling/sobjects/Layout/00h50000000yfyCAAQ"
    },
    "FullName" : "Contact-Magical Happy Land"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Yeah I was trying to give that a shot, but didn't see the actual name of the layout coming back, just the record type name

Comment: see my edit with the response from that endpoint. The names in this section are the record type names and I didn't see anything in the Layouts section to indicate a layout name

Comment: @MattAltepeter Found an answer in the tooling API. Take a peek.

Comment: ah cool! This will work well for me.

Comment: One caveat for future readers: selecting the FullName attribute can only be done when the result will return exactly one layout. Use Name instead to get all the layout names

Comment: @sfdcfox Above solutions only working for standard object and it brings back nothing in case of custom object. I wanted to list down all the page layouts for a specific custom object. Is that possible with JSForce?

Comment: @doga Yes, TableEnumOrId needs to be the Custom Object Id for custom objects. Use a query on CustomObject to find the Id that you need to use.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using only command line interface is to get the complete list of layouts and then filter and clean lines to get the complete list of layouts :

```
sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m Layout -u myOrg | grep -i Fullname | grep SObjectName| cut -d "\"" -f 4
```

- `sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m Layout -u myOrg` gets the json with all layouts
- `grep -i Fullname` removes all lines that are not the layouts names
- `grep SObjectName` filters to keep only the ones concerning the object named SObjectName
- `cut -d "\"" -f 4` is kind of a hack to keep only what's between the 3rd and 4th double-quotes on the line, the layout name.

If you're using windows you should use something like git bash to run the command.

To retrieve all the layouts for a specific object, you could use this :

```
#initialize metadata variable
LAYOUTS=
#build the metadata list string
while read line; do
    LAYOUTS="Layout:$line,$LAYOUTS"
done <<< $(sfdx force:mdapi:listmetadata -m Layout -u myOrg | grep -i FullName | grep SObjectName | cut -d "\"" -f 4)
#remove final comma
LAYOUTS=${LAYOUTS::-1}
echo $LAYOUTS
#retrieve metadata
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m """$LAYOUTS""" -u myOrg
#   if you get a path error using sfdx with git bash, rather use :
#   $LOCALAPPDATA/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx.cmd force:source:retrieve -m """$LAYOUTS""" -u myOrg
```

Hope this can help